# Why the attribute error occurs when importing tensorflow_hub?

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals

import numpy as np

import tensorflow as tf

import tensorflow_hub as hub
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
```

I'm following tensorflow but when I try to import tensorflow_hub, error occurs like

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/PythonProjects/191217_TensorFlow_Project/model3.py", line 7, in <module>
    import tensorflow_hub as hub
  File "C:\Users\UserK\Anaconda3\envs\191217_TensorFlow_Project_1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_hub\__init__.py", line 53, in <module>
    from tensorflow_hub.keras_layer import KerasLayer
  File "C:\Users\UserK\Anaconda3\envs\191217_TensorFlow_Project_1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_hub\keras_layer.py", line 39, in <module>
    class KerasLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'layers'
```

I don't have any file named 'tensorflow_hub.py', so i don't know why it happens.

Comment: `import tensorflow_hub as hub`

Comment: umm... what do you mean?

Comment: `I don't have any file named 'tensorflow_hub.py', so i don't know why it happens.`

Comment: You are importing the class -- so `tensorflow_hub.py` exists in the imported module